# how to print first n column and a column which matches the pattern?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a tab delimited file with n rows and m columns, I want to print the first three column and search for a pattern and print that column if present.
I tried to search and print in sed but unable to do it to print first 3 column and then search for the pattern.

example I have file like

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
test    23      2323    32      635     36354
test2   354     35b     345     345     555
test4   486     g4      435     0.43    34
test5   0.6     35      0.34    0.234   34563
```

output I want is (if pattern I search is 'col6' for example)

```
col1    col2    col3    col6
test    23      2323    36354
test2   354     35b     555
test4   486     g4      34
test5   0.6     35      34563
```

Comment: Please add a sample input file and the sed command that you tried so that it will give more information to people looking at the question

Comment: You want to print the nth column if the header matches the pattern?

Comment: yes but nth column number is not known

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate through the fields when the awk is reading the first line and determine which field `col6` is present,

```
NR==1 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
                if ($i == "col6")
                        column=i
}
{
        print $1, $2, $3, column ? $column : ""
}
```

---

**What it does?**

- `NR==1` If the current number of records(lines) read is 1, then iterate through `NF` number of fields

  - `if ($i == "col6")` if the current column is equal to the string we search, we save it in variable `column`.
- `print $1, $2, $3, column ? $column : ""` Prints the first three fields. The `column` field is printed only if it is set, if not prints empty "".

---

**Example**

```
$ awk 'NR==1{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)if ($i == "col6") column=i}{print $1, $2, $3, column ? $column : ""}' file
col1 col2 col3 col6
test 23 2323 36354
test2 354 35b 555
test4 486 g4 34
test5 0.6 35 34563
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cat /your/file | awk 'NR<=3 {print $0}' | grep 'your-pattern'
```

print the first three column

```
awk 'NR<=3 {print $0}' # if file has headers , NR<=4
```

and search for a pattern and print that column if present

```
grep 'foo'
```

Comment: the pattern is not in first 3 column, grep after awk did not work

Comment: Please read about [Useless Use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552).

Answer (score 2):

In awk:

```
$ awk -v p='col6' -F'\t' '
NR==1 {                                 # on the first record
    split($0,a,FS);                     # split header to array a
    for(i in a)                         # search for index of field with p
        if(a[i]==p)
            c=i                         # set it to c
} 
$0=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3 ( c ? OFS $c : "" ) # print $1-$3 and $c if it exists
' foo 
col1    col2    col3    col6
test    23      2323    36354
test2   354     35b     555
test4   486     g4      34
test5   0.6     35      34563
```

If you want output tab delimited as well, add `-v OFS='\t'` on the command line.